# Is there some sort of official assassin background?

Tags: dnd-5e, background

One of my players wants to play a high elf with the background of a professional assassin.

I went through the player's handbook and looked around the internet but couldn't find any "official" assassin backgrounds or features and starting items for it.

Is there anything I can use or do I just have to homebrew it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The Criminal background represents all kinds of criminals, including assassins.

> There are many kinds of criminals, and within a thieves’
>   guild or similar criminal organization, individual
>   members have particular specialties. Even criminals
>   who operate outside of such organizations have strong
>   preferences for certain kinds of crimes over others.
>   Choose the role you played in your criminal life, or roll
>   on the table below.
>
> \begin{array}{l}
> \text{d8} & \text{Specialty} & \text{d8} & \text{Specialty} \\
> \text{1} & \text{Blackmailer} & \text{5} & \text{Highway robber}  \\
> \text{2} & \text{Burglar} & \text{6} & \textbf{Hired killer} \\
> \text{3} & \text{Enforcer} & \text{7} & \text{Pickpocket} \\
> \text{4} & \text{Fence} & \text{8} & \text{Smuggler}
> \end{array}